# Wrong width of fullcalendar events

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, width

I have a problem with the width of the 10:15 event. 
[image: 10:15 event with wrong size and position]
It should be full width instead of tiny and align to the right.
I would like the cell to be fullfiled by all the events if it has more than one. In case of only one event, it should be full width. Does anyone know how do I do that?

I used the css code below and all the events became full width but when I had 2 events in the same hour it only shows one because the another one is on background.

```
.fc-time-grid-event, .fc-v-event, .fc-event, .fc-start, .fc-end{right: 0px !important;left: 0px !important;margin-right: 0px !important;margin-left: 0px !important;}
```

Comment: sounds like you've been messing with the CSS. First go back to the default CSS and see if that helps. Then add any custom rules back in one at a time until you experience the problem again. I don't believe that the CSS you showed above would cause the event to become right-aligned. However the default is for them to be left-aligned, so the problem must lie elsewhere in code you haven't shown us.